# First Column of excel file not reading oledb reader in window application, excel file data not reading

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

I facing problem to read excel sheet using oledb reader, first column not returning by reader and showing at last column head F14 and column has been empty.
But when I open excel sheet and double click on header row border for auto adjust and auto re size save excel and again read then all columns returning perfectly.

Excel sheet which I try to read that generates using php application and after download that excel we put on my application to read data from excel but above issue come.

I already did lots of R&D even I give width in excel sheet while generating excel using web application. My code is like this

```
private bool Import_To_Grid(string FilePath, string Extension)
        {
            try
            {
                string conStr = "";
                switch (Extension)
                {
                    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                        conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"]
                                 .ConnectionString;
                        break;
                    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 and above
                        conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"]
                                  .ConnectionString;
                        break;
                }
                conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath);
                OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
                OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
                OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();

                cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                //Get the name of First Sheet
                connExcel.Open();
                Exceldt = new DataTable();
                DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                connExcel.Close();

                //Read Data from First Sheet
                connExcel.Open();
                cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
                oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;

                oda.Fill(Exceldt);
                connExcel.Close();

                //Bind Data to GridView
                dgv_showexcel.DataSource = Exceldt;
                BindDataToCmbClass(); //binddata to class for filter
                cmb_userclass.SelectedIndex = 0;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("Its Error" + " " + ex.ToString()); return false; }
        }


Connection string
<add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';" />
<add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';" />
```

Comment: Its urgent I didn't get any thing regarding this please if have any Idea about this please share with me thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to set IMEX=3 for this bcz header place at first column and row default when we downloading its or write mode which locked first cell .

Answer (score 0):

I just solved same problem. Maybe stand someone in good stead.

In my case, the excel file contains a filter on a column. So when reading the file, getting the hidden sheet that named as `_xlnm#_FilterDatabase`.

Actually I expect one sheet, so I am looking at the first row on the schema table. But I get two sheets which one is the filter sheet and this sheet does not contains all columns. So I do not get the first column.

To solve this, loop through schema and get the first sheet name that not contains `FilterDatabase`.

**Code talks:**

```
DataTable excelSchema = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
string sheetName = null;
for (int i = 0; i < dtExcelSchema.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string tableNameOnRow = dtExcelSchema.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    if (!tableNameOnRow.Contains("FilterDatabase"))
    {
       sheetName = tableNameOnRow; 
       break;
    }
 }
 OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
 DataSet ds = new DataSet(); cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
```